# Covert Multipatches to Shapefile and back to Multipatch

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, 3d-analyst, cad, multipatch

I'm working with ArcMap 10.3.1.
I want to convert a CAD-Drawing including Multipatches to Shapefiles and reconvert them.
After reconverting there are hundreds of circles. This Problem is a result of converting Inserts.

Is there a way to avoid These circles?
[image: CAD to SHP]

[image: SHP to CAD]

Comment: What method of conversion have you tried for your CAD? The circles seem to have the same area. Select by attributes -> area greater then-> delete.

Comment: I used the Standard tool "Export to CAD" (Conversion)

Comment: The Problem is not deleting the circles, but the lack of data at Insert geometries from the former AutoCAD-drawing